# Objects colliding with each-other when they shouldn't (SpriteKit)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using **SpriteKit**  and **Swift 2**. I know there are many tutorials but I feel like they must be outdated or I'm going insane because it seems like everybody has a different opinion on what the different physics bit masks do.

I'm just trying to get two objects to collide with everything other than each-other. This is what I've done:

```
var everythingElseCategory: UInt32  = 3
var object1Category: UInt32  = 2
var object2Category: UInt32  = 4

object1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object1;
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = everythingElseCategory

object2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object2;
object2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = everythingElseCategory

everythingElse.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = everythingElseCategory;
everythingElse.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0 //its a wall
```

I must have the concept of bit masks messed up because to me the collision bit mask is what it collides with but it seems I must be wrong because this solution does not work. Object2 collides with object1, but object1 doesn't collide with object2!!!?!??!

Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The key is -> those are bit masks to avoid unwanted behavior it is better you assign them this way  UInt32 = 0x1 << 0.

Comment: [Apple's SpriteKit physics example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW15) may also be of interest.  You are using integer values, where you need to use binary.  Converting these, your collision category is `0011`, where your `object2Category` is `0100`, which means it won't collide.  The easiest way to do that is use bit shifting to create bit masks.

Comment: Have a look at this wikipedia article to get a better understanding of how bitmasks work https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: @Gliderman make your comment an answer so you can get some rep.

Comment: @user3351949 welp that fixed everything... Thankyou so much! And yes you should post that as an answer^^

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Done!  I also expanded it some.

Comment: There already a good answer, I was too lazy to make an answer with the explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving this from my comment.

[Apple's SpriteKit physics example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW15) may be of interest.

You are using integer values, not binary values.  Here is what your values look like in binary:

```
everythingElseCategory = 0011b // I think you need the "b" somewhere to indicate binary
object1Category = 0010b
object2Category = 0100b
```

Basically, SK physics will use the `&` (binary and) operator on the two objects and if the value is not `0`, they will collide.  Take for example your two objects:

```
object1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object1 (0010)
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = everythingElseCategory (0011)

object2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object2 (0100)
object2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = everythingElseCategory (0011)
```

`object1`'s bit mask will collide with `object2`'s because `0010 & 0011 == 0010` or nonzero.  `object2`'s bit mask won't collide with `object1`'s because `0100 & 0011 == 0000` a zero or no collision.

The easiest way to fix this is to use bit shifting.  The syntax looks like this:

```
value = bitValue << placesToShiftLeft
```

So your bit mask setting would look like this:

```
everythingElseCategory = 1 << 0 // I have this shifted by 0 just to show that you can do that
object1Category = 1 << 1
object2Category = 1 << 2
```

Now when you set your bit masks to your objects, use the `|` (binary or) operator to combine them.  `001 | 010 == 011` is how it works.

```
object1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object1Category
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = everythingElseCategory | object2Category

object2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object2Category
object2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = everythingElseCategory | object1Category

everythingElse.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = everythingElseCategory | object1Category | object2Category
```

This will prevent multiple `object1`'s from colliding with each other, but allow colliding with everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to code the collision bit mask is to remember that by default, it's set to UInt32.max i.e. everything collides with everything. If you want a body to collide with everything except specific bodies, it's easier to start with it colliding with everything and then to turn off the bits representing the objects you *don't* want it to collide with e.g.

```
    // Assign the category
object1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = object1Category  
    // Turn off collisions with object1 and object2
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~(object1Category | object2Category)
```

You can turn on and off collisions with specific categories, without affecting any other collisions as follows:

```
    // Turn on collisions with object3
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= object3Category 

    // Turn off collisions with object4
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~object4Category 

    // Turn on collisions with object 5  & 6
object1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= (object5Category | object6Category)
```